# Rsync doesn't preserve UID/GID even w/-a and --numeric-ids

Tags: rsync, backup, file-metadata

I'm trying to use `rsync` to back up remote files, but the UIDs/GIDs on the remote system are different from what I have locally. No matter what I try, all my local files are "opux/opux" both of which have *ID 1000. Here's my rsync:

```
sync -e "ssh" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" -AXSHavz --progress --numeric-ids pi@rpinfs:/mnt/mainhdd/dospace/ --exclude 'videos' ~/backups/dospace/
```

I've tried `--super` and `--fake-super` but the first one just gives me "Operation not permitted" and the 2nd doesn't seem to do anything. How should I go about this?

I know that one way to do backups while preserving all the metadata is to use tar, but as I understand it, it doesn't do remote backups very well. I want something that can be run simply and, ideally, not as root on my local system.

The remote system is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, so the only login user there is root. My local system is Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64.

Answer (score 3):

If you are transferring data from remote then you need not be `root` remotely (unless your SSH user does not have read (and for directories: execute) permission for all affected files.

But if you want rsync to change the owner (and group) of a file locally then it has to run as `root` in general. The exception: If all files and directories shall belong to the same user (which is not the one as which you usually run rsync locally) then you can run rsync as that user.

An alternative solution is to not care about the file metadata with respect to `rsync` at all and handle it separately:

```
getfacl --recursive /mnt/mainhdd/dospace
```

But something has to run as `root` locally. Whether it is better to run `setfacl` as `root` than running `rsync` as `root` is an interesting question...

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to "change" the owner and group, I want to *preserve* the owner and group. Is that what you meant? I'd need to be root to preserve the owner and group? I do care about metadata. The whole point of this is so that I can restore the whole tree back to what it was before if something happens to the remote drive. So like I said, tar would be great for that, but I don't think it works so well remotely

Comment: @PenguinLust Every created file is owned by the creating user. So you really want to change the owner, but this is not permitted without superuser permissions: https://askubuntu.com/a/95988/227119